# space convert to character in php .. is it encoding situation?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, mysqli

i have problem with the space when i use

```
chunk_split()
```

this is my code

```
  echo chunk_split($row_home['text_home'], 19,' ');
```

so my problem it's the space converting to strange character like this

```
 �
```

so what the problem !? is it from encoding or what please ?

i have tried this but don't work

```
 header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
 mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
 mysqli_query($con,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Comment: What does $row_home['text_home'] output?

Comment: PHP's default string methods do not work with Unicode. The character is an indicator that an illegal sequence has occured; almost certainly because `chunk_split` has split a multi-byte UTF-8 character. I suggest using `utf8_chunk_split` from [Portable UTF-8 library](http://pageconfig.com/post/portable-utf8).

Comment: it's outputting a text from sql in arabic .. everything fine and the text show well but the problem is the space convert to this character

Comment: Amadan a lot thaanks i will try

Comment: Space does not convert to this character. If you inspect a bit more closely, you should be missing one character, since space has destroyed it.

Comment: i didn't know .. is the utf8_chunk_split function ? or what .. because i try REPLACE it with chunk_split and it dosen't seem a function >>!

Comment: you mean from where i would be missing character .. in the php code or in sql database ?

Comment: "is the utf8_chunk_split function? or what..." I said: "utf8_chunk_split from [Portable UTF-8 library](http://pageconfig.com/post/portable-utf8)." Follow the link, download the library, require it, then it's a function. "from where i would be missing character" - from the string with the strange character. I don't speak Arabic, but if it was full-width Latin letters, `echo chunk_split("ＦＯＯＢＡＲ", 8, " ");` will display `ＦＯ�� �ＢＡ� ��`, not a pretty sight; notice a missing Ｏ and a missing Ｒ.

Comment: In this case, each of the characters takes up 3 bytes in UTF-8 (an initial byte and two continuation bytes), so if you chunk 8 bytes, you end up with first two characters unchanged in the six bytes, then two bytes of Ｏ, a space, and a final byte of Ｏ. The first byte of the three says there are two continuation bytes, but a space is not a valid continuation byte, so you get �� for the two bytes that now can't be decoded. Then you have a space. Then the last continuation byte from Ｏ, but a continuation byte needs an initial byte to precede it, so this byte too is undecodable, for another �.